# How to install Windows 7 in a PC running Ubuntu 14?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, windows-7, windows-8

I moved to Ubuntu 14 and love everything about it, that is of course until I recently got a job. It has a strict Windows 7 eco system. they do everything there and I personally am saddened but I need to join the club. Anyway, I would like to know how to Install Windows 7, whilst keeping Ubuntu and its information (dual boot).

Comment: "whilst keeping ubuntu and its information" BACK IT UP.

Comment: 2 Methods: 1. you create EMPTY space in FRONT of the disc (takes a long time to complete since ubuntu will need to be moved). 2. wipe it all, partition and install 1st windows and 2nd ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to erase whole disk and install Windows 7 and then Ubuntu. It is not as stupid as it sounds. Installation, drivers setup, system update and work environment configuration of Windows 7 takes a few hours. So additional effort of installing Ubuntu again, which takes only about half an hour, does not really matter.

Comment: oh cool no partition thingy needed? just erase insert and boom?

Comment: @Lostnoob29 mostly yes. Install Windows 7 on whole drive as Windows installer wants by default. Then install Ubuntu and let the Ubuntu installer automatically shrink Windows partition to make place for Ubuntu.